# Facebook comments on Wordpress different comment box for each page

Tags: wordpress, facebook-comments

I have a Wordpress web site, I'm using the Facebook comment. My site is http://66.228.35.100/. Everything is ok but, i want to see different comment box for each different page. I tried to use XID to pick out the pages, but i can't do it,  comment box's style changed to basic (total comment count and it's sublinks are not there). How can I implement different comment box for each page?

You can see the basic style [here](http://66.228.35.100/2011/06/ibm-framework-manager-ve-cognos-10-dan-notlar/) on the bottom page.

Comment: You want to style the box? check `#fbComments`

Comment: No,you can look at two pictures; http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/805/31690282.png/ AND http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/715/54850227.png/